# Need a way to deal with intentional misformattings to circumvent code-only filter

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was doing a triage and faced this problem (not for the first time, though).

[image]

Question link: [send email using Contact fragment using java api. I just got error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286148/send-email-using-contact-fragment-using-java-api-i-just-got-error)

Clearly, if the code had been formatted correctly, it shouldn't have passed detail check, because the question is just the code itself. Questions like this look really ugly and the authors are just too lazy and oftentimes look for **cheap and quick answers without any effort**.

I know/believe that this question should be closed in need of more detail or clarity.

But is there any way for SO to deal with this problem more effectively?

For example: **disable code formatting with tabs** or improve detail check algorithm

## UPDATE

Like @BDL mentioned, this is much likely a trick to circumvent code-only filter. SO needs a way to prevent this type of tricks.

Comment: I didn't know we could format code with tabs?

Comment: It's not unlikely that op missformated on purpose to circumvent the code-only filter.

Comment: @rene some times you can, some times you can't. It's pretty inconsistent. Usually maps to the standard tab action (next element)

Comment: [*On top of that, SE doesn't have a very good track record on "detecting" nonsensical things ("title filter" anyone?) so I rather not have them go implement a feature that is hard to get right, 99% of the times wrong and annoys unsuspecting users that have a valid use case, including the Meta crowd that might have to diagnose these ("your post contains mainly code" anyone?).*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349116/158100)

Comment: @rene I believe just indenting with tabs makes paragraphs that look like code snippets, no?

Comment: @bravemaster I just learned that that sometimes works. it never did for me in the last 6 to 8 years.

Comment: @rene That's how newbies(ok, compared to me) format their code in the first time, or how they think they formatted their code

Comment: @rene Moreover, if they face "your question is mostly of code" message and they cannot get rid of it, they just simply delete some code snippets and pass the detail check. And the question gets uglier even more.

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't) build a system to compensate for the lack of guidance we give to (new) users.

Comment: @rene You're such a great moderator and I got much help from you. But for your last comment, I cannot understand a word.

Comment: @BDL Exactly. I've seen many of them. I'm sure you had too. Any suggestion to help prevent those tricks?

Comment: @bravemaster sorry for being cryptic. What I tried to explain (badly) is that we should focus on guiding new users with editing their posts into shape / format correctly / contains all details etc; *before* they click "ask queston". When you show them an error at that stage, no "checks", "validation lists", error messages, warnings, electro shocks are going to withheld them from posting. The guidance and our expectation  of a question with a code submission should be made clear upfront, when we still have their full attention,  not at the end when their attention is wandering off.